# "Прессы" или "пресса"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Мебельные прессы" или "пресса"?

Answer (score 1):

Множественное число — пресс*ы* (им.падеж). Форма множественного числа пресс*а* (им.падеж) неправильная.